# How to provide Wi-Fi coverage in a larger house

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I asked this question in [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7085/how-to-provide-wi-fi-coverage-in-a-larger-home?noredirect=1#comment11641_7085). I was asked by the moderator to post here:

I've moved into a larger house and I find that my Netgear N600's range is not sufficient to cover the entire house. What I would like to do is have two (or more if needed) Wi-Fi routers provide connectivity using the single broadband connection that I have. So effectively, two resources could be connected to two different Wi-Fi routers but still be on the same network.

At work we have hundreds of Wi-Fi routers spread over several floors all providing access to the same network. So, I think, this should be possible.

However, I have no idea where to start?

PS: Regarding my level of knowledge of networking, I'm no expert. I know how to setup Wi-Fi routers etc. I'm more of a software person.

Comment: What about buying another one that provides more coverage than your Netgear N600 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have another router and 2 powerline adapters, you could use it as an access point (and for the rest of this post, I'll assume you can use powerline adapters on your ring circuit in your house).

At home, I use 2 powerline adapters, and take a line out from the main router and plug it directly into the powerline.

On the other side of the house, I have the other powerline adapter, which I plug into my 'spare' router.

I ensure the 'spare' wireless channel, the SSID and password are the same as the main router which means it's now an access point. This means, I have great coverage and as I move from one end to the other, the mobile device (laptop/tablet/phone) automatically updates to the one with the strongest signal. From my access point, I can also hard wire with an Ethernet cable too. Many good routers actually come with the ability to use the router as an access point (my Belkin does).

There are also plenty of videos on YouTube for converting a router into an access point, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsoJ-NcZFZY

Comment: I'm sorry. Like I mentioned, I'm not much of a h/w guy. What exactly is a power line adapter? I'm sure you're not talking about the normal AC/DC adapters. I have plenty of those around the house.

Comment: @CodePoet You should just Google it, but you plug an ethernet cable into a special plug (the adapter). This plug then plugs into your mains. It uses the wires of your mains to send the ethernet cable around. It means, instead of having, for example, a very long ethernet cable over the entire house, you have 2 short ones.

Comment: See http://content.hwigroup.net/images/products/xl/161887/2/tplink_av200_nano_powerline_adapter_starter_kit.jpg and http://www.macwireless.com/images/powerline/powerline_house_network.gif . I'm a .NET dev, I don't really get networking, never have, never will, but this is plug and play, no installation etc

Comment: Ok got it. I can confirm that there's no power line adapter wiring in my house. Do I have any other options?

Comment: @CodePoet, the powerline adapter doesn't need special wiring... It uses your existing mains cable. Personally, I'd go to your local shop, ask if they'll accept a return if the adapters don't work in your house, and try it out (some units don't work in some houses, depending on the circuits). I've had great success with them in 2 houses, but I do know some who haven't (although I've never had success with repeaters). Any way, 'borrow them' from the shop, stick one direct into your router, stick the other in another room, turn off wifi, plug your laptop in via cable and see if internet works

Comment: rock Thank you. I will research some more into power line adapters. It does sound promising.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend your network and have two or more fixed points in your house you can use a network repeater:

> A network repeater is a device used to expand the boundaries of a wired or wireless (WiFi®) local area network (LAN). In the past, wired repeaters were used to join segments of Ethernet cable. They would amplify the data signals before sending them on to the uplinked segment, thereby countering signal decay that occurs over extended lengths of wire. Modern Ethernet networks use more sophisticated switching devices, leaving the wireless flavor of the network repeater a more popular device for use with wireless LANs (WLANs) at work and home.

Now how you would set this up will depend on the equipment you have available. If you can take it from here to set up a new system then have fun, if you require additional help have a look into this and let us know if you get stuck at any point.

Source - [Wisegeek](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-is-a-network-repeater.htm)